# How to create web server with nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I m using following code for creating server with node js but whenever i run  local host on this port in browser it always show index.html file. What is wrong i do ..

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'html'});
    res.end(index);
}).listen(9615);
```

Comment: It appears to be doing exactly what you told it to. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I am expecting to access my another pages like views/about.html and views/main.html  but whenever i try to access these pages it always open index.html?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to create a router.

Check this: http://www.nodebeginner.org/

Comment: g.mail cyber police: can you provide me generic function for routing in nodejs..i didnt understand from the begginerwebiste.

Answer (score 0):

If you come from a php background, you may expect that creating a file on the server makes it accessible throught an url containing its file name.

In node.js, things work differently. You **must use a routing system**. Basically, you are going to tell that the "route" (url) views/about is the file about.html.

I think that the best option for you is to install **Express** framework : it **will create basic routes** for you, then you'll just have to copy and change some lines to set up new ones.

Express is also going to make a lot of other stuff easier and faster to develop

Have a look at this [5 min Express tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-express--net-33367)

Comment: van you provide me code for generic routing in nodejs

Comment: Express is a generic routing system.

Comment: simply install express with npm and follow any tutorial on the internet. it will be pretty straightforward